# Go back to previous page using unwind segue

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to just go back to my previous page
from Attendance in going to Leave and Leave back to Attendance

LeaveViewController.swift

```
@IBAction func LeaveAttendanceSequeConnect(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "LeaveAttendanceSegue", sender: nil)
    }
```

Attendance.swift

```
 @IBAction func LeaveUnwindSeque(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){

    }
```

and then on my Leave Scene
I have ctrl drag to Exit

[image: after ctrl drag to exit]

Pressing the Back button in Leave wont go back to Attendance

Comment: How did you get to `LeaveViewController` - Via segue?  You don't need the `@IBAction` function - You can just drag from the button's "touch up inside" to the exit icon and select the unwind segue.

Comment: @Paulw11 from attendance I used `performSegue` to go to Leave

Comment: @Paulw11 its still not working

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller? Is the back button the default back button that appears with a navigation controller? You don’t need to do anything to have that work. What type of segue got you to the leave controller? A Show segue?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes im using a navigation controller, im not sure what youre asking for the other questions u have :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of the unwind is incorrect.

```
@IBAction func LeaveUnwindSeque(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){
    }
```

replace with

```
@IBAction func LeaveUnwindSeque(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue){
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The segue should work without needing another segue to leave the unwind. Try this:

1) Keep your original LeaveAttendanceSequeConnect (which should have been bound with ctrl drag from your view controller in story board over to your corresponding .swift file).

2)Get rid of the LeaveUnwindSeque code and unbind that rewind segue properly by deleting the segue (p.s. is segue with a "g" not seque). Now click on the segue connection of the LeaveAttendanceSequeConnect in the storyboard. Make sure the original navigation controller has attributes and looks the same on the storyboard like figures A) and then make sure your second segue has attributes/storyboard like figure B).

A attribute:

[image: Figure A storyboard]

B attribute:

[image: Figure A attributes]

B storyboard:

[image: Figure B storyboard]

A: storyboard:

[image: Figure B attributes]